# How to delete suspended app from market?

Tags: android

I write my first app, I signed the certificate and upload him. After publishing I had to change the certificate so deactivate the application, and I now want to put a new one.

I must create new because certificate is change, but how to delete old?

On upload I get the message: "You have another application on Market with the same package name..."

Comment: Change the package name of your app. Alternatively use your original app and republish it with your updated apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know you can't delete applications from your android market account.. unfortunately you can only "unpublish" them..

Comment: You need to go to APK -> press Switch to advanced mode button in the top right -> Deactivate your published apk

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete applications in Google Play. Any used ID will be permanent. If you get a warning for one application you can access to the application entry then unpublish it. 
If your application is already suspended then you can't unpublish it and the entry will be there with a cross red circle for life.

***Be careful with suspensions because 3 apps suspended make the whole account suspended too.***

Comment: "3 apps suspended make the whole account suspended too" is there any place this is stated?